# Python autoclicker doesn't click

Tags: python-3.10, pynput

```
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode



#----variables----



delay = 1
mouse = Controller()
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='e')
stop_key = KeyCode(char='q')

class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True
    
    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False
#clicker itself
    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
               mouse.click(self.button)
               time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)



#----thread starting----



click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()



#----pause-stop function----



def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == stop_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I work in VSCode, I coded this clicker a long time ago, but now I wanted to test it, and it didn't work. Didn't see the pynput api, so I checked, then I googled, and solved it, just had to re-select the interpreter, from recommended to global, then it worked for like 10 seconds. I accidentally pressed some keys in the console, then pressed enter and it gave me an error. I then deleted console, I don't know why I did that, the nest time it didn't want to work properly.

Like, in the code you can see that "e" is to pause, and "q" to stop program, it works fine, but mouse clicks it doesn't.

Comment: Just in case you run into something similar again, here are the [docs](https://pynput.readthedocs.io).